# Post feed with js sdk to pagewall

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

Im trying to send posts to a wall of a page im an admin to through the js sdk. I have made it do i can do it for myself(my personal user) but i cannot get it to work as the "page".

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SendToFacebook()
        {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId: '**CORRECT ID**',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl: '**MYPAGE**/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status: false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml: true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });

            FB.ui(
               {
                   method: 'feed',
                   name: 'MyFeed',
                   link: '',
                   // picture: '',
                   caption: 'My caption',
                   description: 'test',
                   message: 'MESSAGE?',
               },
               function (response) {
                   if (response && response.post_id) {
                       alert('Delat på facebook.');
                   } else {
                       alert('Inte delat på facebook.');
                   }
               }
             );
            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
            };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }
    </script>
```

This posts to my own user page, and ive tried the "to" parameter but it send the post from my personal user to the page. Is there any way to make this though the login function?
bare in mind that im fairly new to this so demos and examples are welcome.

Comment: You have to use a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). The token is what identifies the current user (and the permissions). When you use your user access token, the post will be posted to your wall because it's *your* token.

Comment: Can you give me a code example of how to do this and maybe a reference?

Comment: all the examples and reference you need are in the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: Well, im fairly new at this so i dont understand everything. Guessing this is what im looking for: "Page access tokens are used in Graph API calls to manage Facebook Pages. To generate a page access token, an admin of the page must grant an extended permission called manage_pages. Once this permission has been granted, you can retrieve the page access token using the following Graph API request:" only that im not using graph api? or have i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work after a hard days work, if any1 is interested heres how i did.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function SendToFacebook()
        {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                // init the FB JS SDK
                FB.init({
                    appId: '***',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                    channelUrl: '***', // Channel file for x-domain comms
                    status: false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                    xfbml: true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
                });


                FB.login(function (response) {
                    FB.api('/me/accounts', function (apiresponse) {

                        var data = {
                            message: "mymessage",
                            display: 'iframe',
                            caption: "caption",
                            name: "name",
                            description: "description",
                            to: **wallid**,
                            from: **wallid**
                        };

                        FB.api('/**wallid**/feed', 'post', data, function () {
                            console.log(arguments);
                        });


                    });

                }, { scope: 'manage_pages' });

            };
            // Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: You save me some big headache. Thanks @Jimmy for posting this

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and I tried it, although I dont know how it was 3 years ago, now you need to append page access token you receive via /me/accounts calling (also you must be admin of that page etc.) so todays working solution could look like this:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', function (apiresponse) {
              console.log(apiresponse);
              var data = {
                  message: "mymessage",
                  //display: 'iframe',
                  caption: "caption",
                  picture: 'www.bla.com/image.jpg',
                  link: 'www.facebook.com',
                  name: "name",
                  description: "description",
                  to: **APP IP**,
                  from: **APP IP**,
                  access_token: apiresponse.data[0].access_token
              };

              FB.api('/**APP IP**/feed', 'post', data, function () {
                  console.log(arguments);
              });
          });
```